# Issue with DefaultPasswordHasher CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Good Morning,

I have got issue with login into my web application.

When I'm registering on my app there is no error (In my opinion):

```
//Register
public function register() {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data('status', '0');
        $this->request->data('role', '0');
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if($this->Users->save($user)) {

            $this->Flash->success('You are registered and can login');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('You are not registered');
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

When the user is registered I cant login (And I dont know why), but if I will login on other user and I'm changing the password for old user -> old user can log in.

I dont know where is the cause of issue.

Login:

```
//Login
public function login() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();

        //dump($user);
        //die();
        if($user) {
            if($user['status'] == '1') {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'tasks']);
            }elseif($user['status'] == '0') {
                $this->Flash->error('You are not authorized to Log In. Please contact with Admin of Application');
            }
        } else {
            //Bad Login
            $this->Flash->error('Incorrect Login or Password');
        }
    }
}
```

The interesting thing is that when I'm logging and i wrote

```
dump($user);
die();
```

I'm receiving "false"...

Login.ctp:

```
<div class="index large-4 medium-4 large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
<div class="panel">
    <center><?= $this->HTML->image('small_logo.png'); ?></center>
    <?= $this->Form->create(); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('email'); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('password'); ?>
        <center><?= $this->Form->submit('Log In', array('class' => 'button')); ?></center>
    <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div>
```

I think the issue is related with 'DefaultHasherPassword' but i dont know where is the issue and how it should be resolved. Please help.

Its like new user cant login, but when the user is modified (password changed) - he can log in.

Comment: if you share your appController auth code then it will easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

You may be forgot to add field username as email (not sure because you didn't share your code)

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email', //email consider as username
                'password' => 'password'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'login'
    ]
]);
```